# Calculating vegetation indices on pansharpened landsat 7 images

Tags: erdas-imagine, landsat-7, pansharpening, evi

I have a problem with calculating vegetation indices like EVI, GSAVI, SAVI on Landsat 7 images after I done a Brovey Transform, Modified Resolution Merge and HCS transformation in Erdas 2013.

My study is based on comparing vegetation indices before and after pansharpening.

I didn't have any problems with calculating vegetation indices before pansharpening.

For calculating vegetation indices after pansharpening I first did TOA, and then with those images I performed pansharpening and then realised I need NIR band for calculating vegetation indices and in pansharpened images I only have R,G,B band.

What can I do?

Comment: Something appears to have gone wrong in your pansharpening process. As far as I know, HCS is capable of pansharpening multispectral data. Perhaps during your TOA-correction you lost the remaining bands?